# Древовидные комментарии на PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите как правильно организовать древовидные комментарии. Алгоритм, какие свойства, методы, технологии. Вообще не могу понять, как сделать ответ на существующий комментарий. Прошу помощи направить в нужное русло в этом вопросе.

Comment: Уточните свой вопрос - что именно вызывает трудности, что вы уже попробовали, почему оно не подошло. В текущей формулировке на ваш вопрос невозможно дать однозначный ответ.

Comment: Вам нужны `Nested sets`

Answer (score 1):

Если совсем грубо изобразить это, то можно добавить в класс свойство, отвечающие за хранение ID комментария, на который отвечают текущим. Это, наверное, самое очевидное решение.

```
class Comment
{
    private $id; //Идентификатор комментария
    private $from_id; //Идентификатор комментария, на который отвечают
    private $text; //Текст комментария
    private $date; //Дата отправки комментария
    private $like; //Количество лайков у комментария

    public function __construct($id = 0, $text="SIMPLE TEXT", $date="21.12.2012 12:00:00", $from_id = NULL) //Конструктор
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->from_id = $from_id;
        $this->text = $text;
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->like = 0;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {

    }

    public function updateText($text="SIMPLE TEXT"){//Редактирование текста
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function addLike(){ //Лайк
        $this->like++;
    }
}
```

Ну а тут простая и ГРУБАЯ(!!!) обработка формы:

```
$com1 = new comment(1, $_POST['commentText'], date("d.m.Y H:i:s")); //Обычный комментарий
$com2 = new comment(2, $_POST['commentText'], date("d.m.Y H:i:s"), 1);//Комментарий-ответ на предыдущий
```

В класс также можно добавить имя пользователя, генерацию ID и прочее, но я думаю вы с этим сами разберетесь.

Comment: скорее у комментария верхнего уровня $from_id будет равен 0, а у вложенного уже какому то значению